# Finding same element in two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two df (df1 and df2) in R each with one column each with the header Person. My real df:s are much longer but example like this :

df1:

```
Person                  
P1
P2
P5
P8
P11
```

df2:

```
Person
P1
P5
P7
P8
P12
```

**I know want to create a new df with just the elements that are the same in both data frames, so in this example it would be:**

newdf:

```
Person
P1
P5
P8
```

I think it should be a commando for this but I cant find one.

Comment: Have you tried `intersect(df1$Person, df2$Person)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(intersect(df1$Person, df2$Person))
```

Comment: if I have 3 df, must i first do intersect df1 and df2 and then dfnew and df3?
Couse intersect(df1,df2,df3) dosent work...

Comment: You can use `intersect` from `dplyr` which takes a data.frame.  For multiple datasets, `Reduce(intersect, list(df1, df2, df3))` But make sure that columns are of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `inner_join` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 inner_join(df1, df2)
 #  Person
 #1     P1
 #2     P5
 #3     P8
```

If there are multiple datasets i.e. >2, one option is `join_all` from `plyr` after placing the datasets in a `list`

```
 df3 <- data.frame(Person=c("P1", "P5"))
 library(plyr)
 join_all(list(df1, df2, df3), by='Person', type='inner')
 #   Person
 #1     P1
 #2     P5
```

You can change the `type` argument according to the need.